# Unable to configure WCF service to be consumed by silverlight client

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0

I am trying hard to develop a duplex wcf service to be consumed by silverlight clients. Now for adventure sake, I decided to use **nettcpbinding**. I understand that the concept of PolicyServer to be running on port 943 is obselete now and it should be served from root of the service.

given Below is config section for the service

```
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="WcfServer.WcfServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />           
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="CrossDomainServiceBehavior">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfServer.WcfServiceBehavior"
      name="WcfServer.MainService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBinding" contract="WCFWebFrontCommunication.IMainService">

      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="CrossDomainServiceBehavior" contract="WCFWebFrontCommunication.IClientAccessPolicy" />

      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <!--<add baseAddress= "http://192.168.0.101:943/WcfServer/MainService" />-->
          <!--<add baseAddress= "http://localhost:943/WcfServer/MainService" />-->
          <add baseAddress= "net.tcp://localhost:4502/WcfServer/MainService" />
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:4502"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>

  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

now at runtime I get an exception **HTTP could not register URL http://+:4502/ because TCP port 4502 is being used by another application**. when Open Method is called.

Am I doing something silly here .., although http exception was there with basicHttpBinding as well

As Troubleshooting:
 checked for open port using **Netstat -aon**
There were some post regarding HTTP configuration followed them nothing happened

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I'm almost sure that you cannot share port between http and net.tcp endpoint. I will be very surprised if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to host a clientaccesspolicy.xml file over HTTP, and use net.tcp on the same port number, that's not going to work. While both of these protocols build on TCP/IP, they are incompatible.

As far as I understand (see also [this article](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-NET.TCP-Protocol-in-Silverlight-4.aspx)), port 943 is still used for this type of thing.

Comment: HI, I forgot to mention that service is self hosted I followed http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/169208/381963.aspx, which suggested changes.  Also I am Getting HTTP could not register URL http://+:<portNumber>/ exception even in basicHttpBinding